# Connecting Netsuite, Shopify and a payment gateway

Tags: payment-gateway, shopify, netsuite

As a disclaimer, I have very limited knowledge of NetSuite so I may be looking at this all wrong, and my research is not shedding much light.

What I am trying to do is connect NetSuite and our payment gateway to our Shopify store. Connecting the payment gateway to Shopify is easy enough, however I am not sure of the order. Should I connect them with NetSuite as the middleman between the payment gateway and Shopify, or should the payment gateway be the middle man between Shopify and NetSuite?

Is it possible to connect NetSuite to Shopify without those $200/month "connector" apps?

Also, any referrals to documentation that can help would be greatly appreciated.

** Also, if there is a better way to ask this question I'd ask that you comment and let me know rather than downvote, which often causes the question to be ignored by potential viewers and thus leaving me stranded without hope of a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You actually can't do that.
Many external carts will export the necessary information to allow you to authorize in one system and capture in another.

Shopify does not export the p/n ref in any fashion I've been able to see. If you had that then you'd be able to do authorization in Shopify and Capture and Settlement in Netsuite.

What my $60/month/store connector app does is use the Shopify transaction and fulfillment apis to let Shopify to settlement and capture for Shopify orders shipped from Netsuite.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pay for any connector to connect to Shopify directly, you can just do it within Netsuite. Just create a private app in Shopify and you can call it within Netsuite. You can use Netsuite as the middle man if you want, that will give you the advantage of define schedules to run it in batches (if you do a scheduled script), or you could create a Restlet/Suitelet to serve as an API endpoint.

Here's some code I posted on my website that will help you get started on getting this done in Suitescript 2.0, just make sure to replace HTTPSMODULE or load with the Netsuite https Module:

```
var SHOP_NAME = 'YOUR_SHOP_NAME';
var API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
var PASSWORD_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'YOUR_PASSWORD_ACCESS_TOKEN';
var URLTEMPLATE = 'https://$APIKEY$:$PASSWORD$@$SHOP$.myshopify.com'
                .replace('$SHOP$', SHOP_NAME)
                .replace('$APIKEY$', API_KEY)
                .replace('$PASSWORD$', PASSWORD_ACCESS_TOKEN);

function run(){
    var myUrl = URLTEMPLATE;
    var path = '/admin/orders.json';
    myUrl += path;

    var orders = shopifyRequest(myUrl);
    var ordersJSON = JSON.parse(orders);
    return orders;
}

function shopifyRequest(myurl){
    var myrequest = {};
    myrequest.url = myurl;
    myrequest.method = HTTPSMODULE.Method.GET;
    myrequest.headers = {};
    myrequest.headers["X-Shopify-Access-Token"] = PASSWORD_ACCESS_TOKEN;
    var myresponse = HTTPSMODULE.request(myrequest);
    return myresponse.body;
}
```

Taken from:
[Getting JSON from a Shopify Private App in Netsuite](https://ursuscode.com/netsuite-tips/getting-json-from-a-shopify-private-app-in-netsuite/)

Comment: Thanks for sending this over, I'll take a look into it.

Comment: This solution isn't going to fit within our time frame, so we just went with a connector app. With that said, we are revisiting these post-launch, and I will attempt to implement your solution then. It may take a while, but if it works at that time I will mark this as correct then.